# How can I disable the bootstrap hover color for links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, href

I am using Bootstrap.

Bootstrap defines

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #005580;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I have this links / CSS-classes

```
<a class="green" href="#">green text</a>
<a class="yellow" href="#">yellow text</a>
```

How can I disable the hoover color?

I want the green links to stay green and the yellow ones yellow, without overriding :hover for every single class? (this question is not mandatory dependent to bootstrap).

I need something like

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: @nonhoovercolor;
}
```

and I think

```
.yellow {
    color: yellow !important;
}
```

is not a good practice.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

if anyone cares i ended up with:

```
a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I care wutzebaer...I care

Comment: This inherits the anchor tag's parent's color. It doesn't just grab the color it was before being hovered right? So for this to work his markup would have to be `<div class="yellow"><a>Link</a></div>` in order for this to work. Is that correct?

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland cares

Comment: It didnot work for me. I also needed same thing. I have img inside <a href and when I hover nothing must happen. I am getting some default hover color

Comment: In my case I needed `background-color: inherit;`, thanks!

Comment: answer of the day

Comment: In case you care and this did not work for you: add !important.

Answer (score 14):

I would go with something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vXC5/):

HTML:

```html
<a class="green" href="#">green text</a>
<a class="yellow" href="#">yellow text</a>
```

CSS:

```css
body  { background: #ccc }
/* Green */
a.green,
a.green:hover { color: green; }
/* Yellow */
a.yellow,
a.yellow:hover { color: yellow; }
```

Comment: i asked: "without overriding :hover for every single class"

Comment: well, i guess it would be much better and good practice to remove link style from the bootstrap.css and re-style it as you want!

Comment: Might want to add !important; just in case.

Answer (score 10):

```
a {background-color:transparent !important;}
```

Comment: add some explanations too.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer with some additional information and understanding. Just a block of code is unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: This is irrelevant. bootstrap only adds text color, not a background.

Answer (score 5):

For me none of the simple solutions above worked, however by changing only the hover I was able to get it to work:

```
  :hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you like an ugly hacks which you should never do in real worlds systems; you could strip all :hover style rules from document.styleSheets.

Just go through all CSS styles with JavaScript and remove all rules, which contain ":hover" in their selector. I use this method when I need to remove :hover styles from bootstrap 2.

```
_.each(document.styleSheets, function (sheet) { 
    var rulesToLoose = []; 
    _.each(sheet.cssRules, function (rule, index) { 
        if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.indexOf(':hover') > 0) { 
            rulesToLoose.push(index);
        }
    });

    _.each(rulesToLoose.reverse(), function (index) {
        if (sheet.deleteRule) {
            sheet.deleteRule(index);
        } else if (sheet.removeRule) {
            sheet.removeRule(index);
        }
    });
});
```

I did use underscore for iterating arrays, but one could write those with pure js loop as well:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {}
```

Comment: Plus one for a charming hack

Comment: I would write more code for an ugly hack :P

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Bootstrap expert, but it sounds to me that you should define a new class called **nohover** (or something equivalent) then in your link code add the class as the last attribute value:

```
<a class="green nohover" href="#">green text</a>
<a class="yellow nohover" href="#">yellow text</a>
```

Then in your Bootstrap LESS/CSS file, define **nohover** (using the JSFiddle example above):

```
a:hover { color: red  }
/* Green */
a.green  { color: green; }
/* Yellow */
a.yellow  { color: yellow; }
a.nohover:hover { color: none;  }
```

Forked the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9rpkq/

Comment: hm so color:none is the trick? i'll try it but i'm on holydays for now =)

Answer (score 1):

Mark `color: #005580;` as `color: #005580 !important;`.

It will override default bootstrap hover.

Comment: this is not the answer, bootstrap says that hoovered links get the color #005580, but i want to override this definition that the color stays as it is

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a default color for links but continue using [wutzebaer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18460960/4700922) try this:

```css
body a {
    color:pink; /*this is the default link color*/
}
a {
  color:inherit;
}
.green {
  color:green
}
.red {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<a class="green">Green</a>
<a class="red">Red</a>
<a>Default</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are still looking for answer for a question that is more than 8 years old - Bootstrap since v4.2 has `.text-reset` class for this use-case (that basically implements wutzebaer answer). See docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/text/#reset-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

By changing your color classes to:

```
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
    --color: yellow;
}
```

You can then reference this variable in the hover/focus class to overwrite default behavior:

```
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: var(--color);
}
```

This will default to `color: unset;` if there is no class on the element that assigns the variable.

You can setup some safeguards around this by declaring a global default, or a fallback in the hover class:

```
:root {
    --color: default-color;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: var(--color,fallback-color);
}
```